# NextJS doesn`t render new state to UI (but to the console)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When the state of "address" changes, it is recognized in the browser console, but not in the server console and NextJS doesn't render the new state to the screen.

If I HARDCODE the wished state it works fine:

```
const StationList = ({ stations }) => {
  const address = 71522

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rerendering', address)
  }, [address])

  console.log('address is now: ', address)
  return (
    <div>
      {stations.map((station) => {
        if (station.plz === address) {
          return (
            <Station
              key={v4()}
              name={station.name}
              straßenname={station.straßenname}
              straßennummer={station.straßennummer}
              plz={station.plz}
              ort={station.ort}
            />
          )
        }
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default StationList
```

If I let the state define the address, it doesn't work, but the console is logging the correct state :/

This is the code:

```
const StationList = ({ address, stations }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rerendering', address)
  }, [address])

  console.log('address is now: ', address)
  return (
    <div>
      {stations.map((station) => {
        if (station.plz === address) {
          return (
            <Station
              key={v4()}
              name={station.name}
              straßenname={station.straßenname}
              straßennummer={station.straßennummer}
              plz={station.plz}
              ort={station.ort}
            />
          )
        }
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default StationList
```

And this is the problem:
[Picture of my browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQL3M.png)

EXPLANATION (it's easy): I defined a default State of 73529 for the address in index.js. I use this state in StationList.js to render only that Stations to the screen which zip-codes are equal to the current state. When clicking an option of the Selection-Dropdown it updates the state of address to the selected number (zip-code). The problem is that this changed state does not get rendered to the screen, but the console logs the new state... When I HARDCODE the state, then it's working just fine.

Comment: Looking at picture looks like your address code is somehow a string. Put too console  console.log('address': , typeof address, 'plz: ',  typeof station.plz)

Comment: @DarthJS THANKS SO MUCH :D  I just overlooked that. I fix that now and reply if its then works. But I'm sure it will^^

Comment: It works! The only change I made was to remove one "=" from "station.plz === address"